# How to delete a row from HTML table using the button which is in the next cell of the data entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code which I was working on. Basically it is the Library Management Project for the final semester in my college.

Now my question is how to delete a row when we click that row's delete button.

```
        <table border="1" id="student_tb1" class="table table-bordered" style="display: none;" contenteditable="true">
            <tr>
                <td>Sr. No.</td>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td>Roll no</td>
                <td>Name</td> 

            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addStudent(){
    var maxRows = 10; 
    var table = document.getElementById("student_tb1");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("student_textbox1").value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("student_textbox2").value;
    var text3 = document.getElementById("student_textbox3").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("book_tb1").rows.length;
    var message;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
       if(x <= maxRows)  {

        if(text1 == "select" ){
           message.innerHTML = "select the class !!  " 

        }
        else if(text2 == ""  || isNaN(text2) || text2 < 0 || text2 > 100 || text2 == 0){
            message.innerHTML = "your roll no may be between 0 and 101 " 
        }
        else if (text3 == "") {
            message.innerHTML = "enter the name"
        }

        else{

        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

        cell2.innerHTML = text1;
        cell3.innerHTML = text2;  
        cell4.innerHTML = text3;

                for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {

                    cell1.innerHTML = i+1;
                }

            }
            alert("Data has been inserted successfully!");
        }|
    }
    </script>
```

Result:

```
Sr. No. |Class    |Roll no |Name     |Action
1       |BSCIT-3  |010     |vishesh  |Delete button
```

Comment: Where is this delete button, can you show us the result html?

Comment: i've added the result, in which last button is delete. i want that entire row to be deleted on button click , what should i do about it

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function:

```
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

and make your delete button html:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
```